# Block incoming connections but outgoing UDP is also blocked?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I am trying to block all incoming connection with IPTABLES and selectively allow ports and services. That is working fine, but when I do that, I can not perform outgoing DNS queries correctly. I have tried to allow incoming port 53 TCP and UDP for DNS but that didn't work either. Oh and all outgoing traffic is allowed.

This is the output of iptables -L -n -V
http://pastebin.com/qNGJQq7J

Comment: That's bad. And what is your current ruleset?

Comment: As mailq says, please do an `iptables -L -n -v` and paste the output into your question.

Comment: This is what I get when I run that command: http://pastebin.com/qNGJQq7J

Comment: All but one of your rules allow packets to get thru your firewall. The one that blocks is just to block all from one specific host. The DNS problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @ott--: You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 0):

All but one of your rules allow packets to get thru your firewall. The one that blocks is just to block all from one specific host. The DNS problem must be somewhere else.